# Querying for value based on three keys/values

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this following table (I'm thinking of putting this as a `datatable`, but I'm flexible):

```
ID(int)   Branch(string)   Department(string)   Available(Boolean)

 101          North           Sales               True
 101          North           Marketing           False
 102          North           Security            True
 103          South           Sales               True
 ...          ...             ...                 ...
```

I want to be able to query `Available` through `[ID][Branch][Department]`

So something like `[101]["North"]["Marketing"]` would give me `False`, or at least tell me whether a row containing `[101]["North"]["Marketing"]` exists or not in the table.

What's the most efficient way to go about this?
Feel free to suggest some other structure if you think it's more efficient than a `datatable`

Comment: Where are you storing the data? In memory, or on a remote database?

Comment: I should add that it's not going to be in some database. It'll just be in memory as a small lookup table. There's probably not going to be more than 20 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the DataTable's PrimaryKey to be the first 3 columns then use DataTable's Rows.Find(101, "North", "Marketing") to fish out the row or get null if it doesn't exist!

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataTable's [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method.
Like

```
datatable.Select("ID = 101 AND Branch='North' AND Department = 'Marketing'");
```

Answer (score 1):

> I should add that it's not going to be in some database. It'll just be in memory as a small lookup table. There's probably not going to be more than 20 rows.

In that case, the most *efficient* method, both for performance and memory footprint, would be to use an enumeration for Branch and Department and to use your triple-nested array approach.

That having been said, both it and simple datatable would be a maintenance nightmare. I would suggest you consider well-defined types.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a small amount of data in memory, why not use LINQ to objects and make custom business objects for your data?  It would be more efficient than a `DataTable`.

```
public class Branch
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string BranchName {get;set;}
  public string Department {get;set;}
  public bool Available {get;set;}
}

public bool BranchExists(int id, string branch, string dept)
{
   //assume "Branches" is your in-memory list
   return Branches.Any(b => b.id == id && b.BranchName == branch && b.Department == dept);
}
```